# How to use two conditions in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following equation:

```
result=[(i,j,k) for i in S for j in S for k in S if sum([i,j,k])==0]
```

I want to add another condition in the if statement such that my result set does not contain (0,0,0). I tried to do the following:
`result=[(i,j,k) for i in S for j in S for k in S if sum([i,j,k])==0 && (i,j,k)!=(0,0,0)]` but I am getting a syntax error pointing to the `&&`. I tested my expression for the first condition and it is correct.

Comment: What is the type of `S`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the [`and` boolean operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead:

```
result=[(i,j,k) for i in S for j in S for k in S if sum([i,j,k])==0 and (i,j,k)!=(0,0,0)]
```

`&&` is [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html), [Perl](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-operators.html), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), Ruby, Go, OCaml, Haskell, MATLAB, R, Lasso, ColdFusion, C, C#, or C++ boolean syntax instead.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from that error instead of triple nested for-loops you can also use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here to get the Cartesian product of `S * S * S`:

```
from itertools import product
result=[ x for x in product(S, repeat = 3) if sum(x)==0 and x != (0,0,0)]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> S = [1, -1, 0, 0]
>>> [ x for x in product(S, repeat = 3) if sum(x) == 0 and x != (0,0,0)]
[(1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0), (1, 0, -1), (1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, -1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, -1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
result = [(i, j, k) for i in S
          for j in S
          for k in S
          if sum([i, j, k]) == 0 and (i, j, k) != (0, 0, 0)]
```